# Wiring a transformer

Tags: transformer

I have this transformer I have 240 going in and only 56 coming out should be 110. Is that jumper correct for 240? On other transformers for 240 i have two jumpers on the outside and when it’s 480 one jumper in middle.

[image]

Comment: Transformer has two primary windings for 230V with taps for 220V. In pic two windings connected in serial, input voltage will be summarized, so that connection for 460V. That why you getting 56V instead 110.

Comment: For 240V you need to remove middle jumper from 0V and connect to 220V on right.

Comment: A good answer was given by vu2nan, this is what I would do. But, if you have any documentation on this  device, you should study it. You should be really sure when dealing with high voltages like this.

Answer (score 2):

The primary windings are to be connected in series for 460 V and in parallel for 230 V.

[image]

[image]

The output voltage is halved as a result of connecting the primary windings in series and applying 230V instead of 460 V.

Comment: Parallel connection of primary windings decrease resistance, increase idle current. That reduce transformer efficiency. Not really essential.

Answer (score 1):

Try this but use a 5 amp fuse just in case: -

[image]

The idea here is that this should give an equivalent primary rating of 240 volts rather than 230 volts. So the main primary winding has taps at 0 and 230 volts then, I'm suggesting using the 2nd primary winding in series with the main primary winding but only the 220/230 taps. Thus, the overall primary should then be rated for 240 volts.